# eval in clojure

Tags: clojure

How to evaluate this in clojure.

I want

```
(xml-eval '(item (itemname "some item") (price (% * 19.95 1.08))))
```

to be evaluated to

```
(xml-eval '(item (itemname "some item") (price 21.54))
```

Comment: What are the defs for xml-eval item and itemname? I'd love to play around with this, but have no context for the code snippit. Could you add more detail?

Comment: clujure has eval just like scheme/racket. I want to execute line 1 to get line 2 as return.

Comment: Yes, it has eval, but not xml-eval. I've tried running it in repl with eval, and it balks on item.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I want to define xml-eval that takes a list.

Comment: And what exactly should xml-eval do. I see the input & output but can you describe how you would use it?

Comment: Ok. I want to call xml-eval as specified in line 1. and I want it to return me '(item (itemname "some item") (price 21.54)

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 That's just Input & output again ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do and why you're naming this function xml-eval.

But it seems you need a function that takes a bunch of nested lists and replace those that start with *%* by the result of the code they contain. So you may want to use something like this:

```
(defn xml-eval [x]
      (if (coll? x)
          (if (= (first x) '%)
              (eval (rest x))
              (map xml-eval x))
          x))
```

That seems to do what you want.

```
user=> (xml-eval '(item (itemname "some item") (price (% * 19.95 1.08))))
(item (itemname "some item") (price 21.546))
```

But you may also want to look into [unquoting](http://clojure.org/reader#toc2)

```
user=> `(item (itemname "some item") (price ~(* 19.95 1.08)))
(user/item (user/itemname "some item") (user/price 21.546))
```

Comment: From where does he get xml-eval?

Comment: I want to define xml-eval that takes xml style list with list item as (price (expression)). and I expect the expression to be evaluated.

Comment: @alexadre: Thanks for the solution, it works in clojure REPL. I want to take it a step further to define xml-eval. Could you help.